# Use rest parameters instead of arguments - Angular ES6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I am trying to access the component this inside a nested function using an arrow method. When I use the arrow method, I get a compiler error "error TS2496: The 'arguments' object cannot be referenced in an arrow function in ES3 and ES5. Consider using a standard function expression."

I read about it and was trying to convert it to rest paramters but not sure how to get it to work.

Before rest paramters:

```
    ((H => {
        H.wrap((H as any).seriesTypes.sunburst.prototype, 'drillUp', (proceed) => {

            proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

            console.log('drillup');
                 this.drillUpClick();

        });
    }))(Highcharts);
```

After rest params:

```
    ((H => {
        H.wrap((H as any).seriesTypes.sunburst.prototype, 'drillUp', (proceed, ...args) => {

            proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));

            console.log('drillup');
            this.drillUpClick();

        });
    }))(Highcharts);
```

I am not able to get the console.log fired up. Get an error "Cannot read property undefined of undefined"

Please advice.

Comment: `proceed.apply(this, args);`

Comment: Nope. Didnt work. Still the same error.

Comment: Nope, but probably it's naging about `this` now, wich arrow-functions also don't have. And there is no alternative for that. you need to use a regular `function(proceed, ...args){ proceed.apply(this, args); ... }`

Comment: Sounds like that. Now the drillup functionality stopped working.

Comment: Show us the call to `drillUp` function

Comment: drillUpClick() {
    console.log('hi');
  }

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to access the component's scope this so I can call in this function. That is why I wanted to proceed with an arrow function instead of a normal function, And I think the value of args is always empty, so the proceed function doesnt get called and doesnt drill up the chart. This is what I followed: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

`args` is already your rest arguments. So don't slice the array:

```
((H => {
    H.wrap((H as any).seriesTypes.sunburst.prototype, 'drillUp', (proceed, ...args) => {
        if(args && args.length > 0) {
            proceed.apply(this, args);
        }
        console.log('drillup');
        this.drillUpClick();

    });
}))(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Ensure that `args` is defined with `if(args && args.length > 0)`

Comment: Logged args and it returns an empty array.

Comment: if (args && args.length > 0) {
                console.log(args)
              }

Its not printing the args argument at all.